# JSON-like serialization/config notation, but it's not JSON (nor YAML)

Tags: json, yaml, notation

**UPDATE**: I might be thinking of nginx configs.  More later.

Anyone know what this format is called?

I remember seeing a data notation in the last three months or so that resembles JSON, and somewhat resembles YAML, but it's without quotes and commas, and isn't indent-sensitive, and is perhaps one atom or pair per line.  Something like that.  If I recall correctly, it looks sort of like this:

```
{
   my_first_name: Eneri
   my_last_name: Ikkuddan
   my_homeworld: Efate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Universal Configuration Language: https://github.com/vstakhov/libucl

Comment: That's not quite it, but you may have hit on the solution inadvertently, in that UCL is based on ngnix configs.  I'll do some digging.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [the Eclog format](https://www.eclog.org/), and maybe you will like it.

This is an example:

```
# Person.ecl

firstName: John
lastName: Smith

isAlive: true
age: 27

address:
{
    streetAddress: "21 2nd Street"
    city: "New York"
    state: NY
    postalCode: "10021-3100"
}

phoneNumbers:
[
    { type: home, number: "212 555-1234" }
    { type: office, number: "646 555-4567" }
    { type: mobile, number: "123 456-7890" }
]

children: []
spouse: null
```

In addition to unquoted strings, it also provides raw strings and heredoc strings.